# realloc: invalid checksum for freed object

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc, realloc

I have an error using `realloc` to replace `malloc`.

This code below runs OK on my computer.

```
int vector_grow(Vector* vec) {
  unsigned long newcap;
  int * newarr;

  if (0 == vec->cap) {
    vec->arr = (int*)malloc(START_CAPACITY * sizeof(*vec->arr));
    if (NULL == vec->arr)
      return -1;
    vec->cap = START_CAPACITY;
    return 0;
  }
  newarr = malloc (newcap * sizeof(*vec->arr));
  if (NULL == newarr)
    return -1;

  memcpy (newarr, vec->arr, vec->len * sizeof(*vec->arr));
  free (vec->arr);
  vec->arr = newarr;
  vec->cap = newcap;

  return 0;
}
```

I want to change the `malloc` to `realloc`, but the error occurs.

```
int vector_grow(Vector* vec) {
  unsigned long newcap;

  if (0 == vec->cap) {
    vec->arr = (int*)malloc(START_CAPACITY * sizeof(*vec->arr));
    if (NULL == vec->arr)
      return -1;
    vec->cap = START_CAPACITY;
    return 0;
  }
  newcap = 2 * vec->cap;
  if ((vec->arr = (int*)realloc(vec->arr, newcap * sizeof(int))) == NULL)
    return -1;
return 0;
}
```

It says

> malloc: *** error for object 0x7fca64c02598: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.

I don't know any difference between those two snippets of code, if you know what causes the error, please tell me! Thank you very much!

Comment: Note that using `realloc()` like that causes a potential memory leak.

Comment: in the first code snippet variable `newcap` isn't initialized at all?!

Comment: .unintuitive feel conditions Yoda Also

Comment: You're not updating `vec->cap` in the updated code, so you're probably incorrectly detecting when you're at capacity.  I can't say however if that's the cause of your issue as the rest of what you've shown seems ok.  Try running your code through [valgrind](http://valgrind.org).  That should tell you where you're running afoul with your memory.

Comment: The value of newcap is undefined when malloc is called in the first code.  Also, don't cast the output of malloc or realloc.  It hides errors.

Comment: Thank you! I see a few leaks in valgrind, I will improve it! @dbush

Comment: Thank you all for the valuable advices!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bug in missing `vec->cap =` in updated code certainly contribute to various calls to `malloc()` and calling code's misuse of data.

```
int vector_grow(Vector* vec) {
  unsigned long newcap;

  if (0 == vec->cap) {
    ... // not important to show the bug
  }
  newcap = 2 * vec->cap;
  if ((vec->arr = (int*)realloc(vec->arr, newcap * sizeof(int))) == NULL)
    return -1;

  // Add missing update  
  vec->cap = newcap;

  return 0;
}
```

Also better to test for allocation success

```
  void *p = realloc(vec->arr, sizeof *(vec->arr) * newcap);
  if (p == NULL) {
    return -1;
  }

  vec->arr = p;
  vec->cap = newcap;
```

Answer (score 0):

The only scenario where I can imagine such error message is when you actually modify the pointer, for example

```
int *x = malloc(2 * sizeof *x);
if (x != NULL) {
    x = x + 1;
    free(x);
}
```

The pointer that MUST be passed to `free()` MUST had been returned by `malloc()`/`calloc()`/`realloc()`, passing any other pointer including a pointer to the same data but at a different position like `x` in the example above is *undefined behavior*.